# iTunes can't find library file on NFS server

Tags: itunes, libraries, nfs

I've set up an [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) server to maintain a central iTunes media folder for all users on our home network. In addition, we are storing each user's library file on the NFS, and pointing the iTunes client on each workstation to the user's library file on the NFS. This works well for a single workstation.

However, when a user goes to access their iTunes on another workstation, iTunes can't find the media. The media file location preference is set to the iTunes folder in each client, so I don't understand why this is not working.

I've accessed the library XML file and the iTunes media file pointer seems to be correct.  Now, if I try and locate the media files on the second workstation, the first workstation will not be able to find them.

I used this same configuration when using one of the workstations as a centralized repository for iTunes media, and it worked fine.

Any ideas here?

Comment: When you say you're pointing each client to a library file, is it an itunes specific type of file? Perhaps it dictates what files have been added to that library and results in "piracy prevention" for files in other libraries. Can you `add - files or folder` from one "library" to another "library" on the clients?